# How do I convert a tensor to a Numpy array within a Tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to make an LSTM model using this code provided in a Deeplearning.AI tutorial on Coursera.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 64),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

However, I get this error:

```
"Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (bidirectional_4/forward_lstm_4/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported"
```

If I drop the bidirectional layers, the code runs fine.

I know that there are several other questions dealing with the issue of converting tensors to numpy arrays. However I can't find one that addresses my issue because:

a) They all deal with doing so outside of a model. My issue is that the model is failing to even be instantiated because one layer seems to have trouble talking to another and I haven't found a solution that deals with that and

b) This is the exact same code that runs just fine inside a Colab notebook (with the same TF version as on my desktop) but fails on my desktop.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a problem with numpy versions 2.0 and above. When I downgraded my numpy version to 1.19.5, it worked just fine.